# C++ File not read?

Tags: c++, io

I want to read a file line by line. Did something like

```
void Parse (string filepath) {
    ifstream sourceFile;
    sourceFile.open(filepath);
    for (string line; getline(sourceFile, line);) {
        cout << "1" << endl;
        cout << line << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    Parse("C:\\test.txt");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Then put some text into `C:\test.txt`, but when I run, I dont get anything. Why? Not even the "1". I notice no exception if the file is not there too. I suppose that a sign of a problem?

Comment: No exception is thrown if it can't find the file.

Comment: Use this syntax to open the file.`sourceFile.open(filepath.c_str());`

Comment: This code works fine for me. @CodingMash, C++11 added the string constructor, and the OP did say run, so I can only presume it compiled fine.

Comment: Yes, compiled fine in VS2010 C++ Express. Still nothing when I try with `.c_str()`

Comment: @chris, if no exception is thrown how do I know if the read was successful at all?

Comment: @JiewMeng, Because `std::istream` has `explicit operator bool()`, `good()`, and `fail()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have problems opening the file. I would suggest two things:

- check if sourceFile is opened successfully(`if (sourceFile)`)
- debug the code and see the code path your code follows.

EDIT: adding the actual solution to the problem in my answer(instead of just a comment) so that people won't miss it:

Here is one more thought - check the file name in its properties. Has happened to me that if windows hides the extension of the file the name is actually test.txt.txt, while what I see displayed is only test.txt.

Comment: Ok seems like it failed opening file `if (sourceFile)` goes to else clause

Comment: Here is one more tought - check the file name in its properties. Has happened to me that if windows hides the extension of the file the name is actually test.txt.txt, while what I see displayed is only test.txt. This can drive a man crazy!

Answer (score 3):

You have to check for success/error manually. Try with [`ifstream::good()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/good/):

```
sourceFile.open(filepath);
if(!sourceFile.good()) {
  // do something
```

If you don't want to check manually, you can enable [exceptions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/exceptions/):

```
// call that before open()
sourceFile.exceptions ( ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit );
```

Comment: Note that `if(soureFile.fail())`, `if(!sourceFile.is_open())` and `if(!sourceFile)` all work equally well in this context.

Comment: Seems like the sourcefile is not good ... the file is just a simple text file in that c: ...

Comment: @JiewMeng maybe your application doesn't have the access rights. Try putting the .txt file in your .exe's working directory, and update the path.

Comment: I tried putting the txt file in D:\parsertry\Debug where is my VS project folder ... not working either ... of course I changed filepath to `test.txt`

Comment: @JiewMeng Try `perror(filepath.c_str())` in the "do something" section.

Answer (score 0):

change your for loop to

```
for (string line; sourceFile.good();) {
    getline(sourceFile, line);

}
```

This way, you check the validity of your stream in the conditional part of the for, and get the line if the stream good.

Comment: This is incorrect, as the first iteration of the loop run before the first call to `getline()`.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my earlier comment. This edit is also incorrect. You don't check the condition of the stream *after* `getline` and *before* `operator<<`.